# How to import files from a directory above the notebook directory?

Tags: import

Consider some directory

.../a/

where ... may be some arbitrary path.

It has two subdirectories:

/a/b/

and

/a/c/

In the subdirectory /a/c/, a Mathematica notebook is located, while in the subdirectory /a/b/, a file file.txt is located.

How to import the file.txt in the Mathematica notebook? Precisely, what is the Mathematica's analog of `..` used in Linux in order to go from the `NotebookDirectory[]` to the upper directory?

Comment: I believe you are looking for: `ParentDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
`

Comment: "." and ".." work in MMA the same as in Unix. E.g. FileNames[All, "."] gives all names in the current working directory. And "FileNames[All, ".."]" all names in its parent directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notebook's Directory:

```
acDir = NotebookDirectory[]
(* "C:\\Users\\rpotter\\Desktop\\" *)
```

Directory above that:

```
aDir = ParentDirectory[acDir]
(* "C:\\Users\\rpotter" *)
```

"b" directory in directory above notebook's directory:

```
abDir = FileNameJoin[{aDir, "bDir"}]
(* "C:\\Users\\rpotter\\bDir" *)
```

Full path of file:

```
myFilePath = FileNameJoin[{abDir, "file.txt"}]
(* "C:\\Users\\rpotter\\bDir\\file.txt" *)
```

Or all at once with:

```
myFilePath = 
 FileNameJoin[{ParentDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]], "bDir", 
   "file.txt"}]
(* "C:\\Users\\rpotter\\bDir\\file.txt" *)
```

Then import with:

```
fileData=Import[myFilePath]
```